# Are perfect and simple tenses interchangeable in these examples? Do they have any difference?

Tags: tense, future-tense, past-vs-past-perfect, future-perfect

Sci-fi movies earned the most income each year between 2006 and 2010.

Sci-fi movies had earned the most income each year between 2006 and 2010.

It is forecast that car ownership will decline by 10% in the next five years.

It is forecast that car ownership will have declined by 10% in the next five years.

Comment: #2 is only valid if it's in a context where the primary temporal focus is on some time in the ***past*** that's ***after*** 2010 (so you can use the Past Perfect to refer to a period of time ***before*** that). But in practice most people would still use Simple Past (#1) even then. And #4 is *always* invalid, because ***in the next five years*** refers to a ***span, period*** of time, but the "Past in the Future" reference ***will have declined*** needs to be attached to an adverbial element denoting a ***fixed point*** in future time.

Comment: The two tenses exist to describe different things, and so, they are not interchangeable. This is a common ELL problem, thinking that A=B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sci-fi movies earned the most income each year between 2006 and 2010.

> Sci-fi movies had earned the most income each year between 2006 and 2010.

> It is forecast that car ownership will decline by 10% in the next five years.

> It is forecast that car ownership will have declined by 10% in the next five years.

Examples 1 and 3 are fine, but examples 2 and 4 are not.

Constructions in examples 2 and 4 are suitable to form part of other sentences.

> Sci-fi movies had earned the most income each year between 2006 and 2010 *by the time their popularity went down*.

> It is forecast that car ownership will have declined by 10% in the next five years *by the time new initiatives are implemented*.